# OpenVAS: Add 3rd Party Feed

Tags: security, network-security, port-scanning, openvas

Tried searching around but not finding anything. Hoping someone will know the answer. Is it possible to add more than the 3 feeds that come with OpenVAS? Looking to add feeds from NVD so I can scan with them. Doesn't seem to be possible via the WebGUI.

Answer (score 0):

Feeds from e.g. the NVD probably won't help you. They would need to provide scripts written in NASL if you would like to use them. One of the following blogposts might give you some background knowledge on this topic:

https://avleonov.com/2017/06/30/adding-third-party-nasl-plugins-to-openvas/

https://avleonov.com/2017/10/04/vulners-nasl-plugin-feeds-for-openvas-9/